# SQL agent job calling powershell script with "PSExe \\server diskpart /s filename" hangs and never complete

Tags: windows, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, psexec

The script is a simple script that will remotely unmount/offline disk(s).

I wrote a powershell script that I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 job (choose powershell) calling it to accomplish the following commands, but it never does anything and didn't return any failures.

The command in powershell script is:

PSExec \TargetServer Diskpart /s C:\Test.txt

Within Test.txt (this file exist on the TargetServer)
Select Disk 3
Offline Disk

Does anyone know what's going on there? Permission issue?

Is this the best way to do it? If not, what would be a better way?

I can manually run the powershell script on my source server (it works and can offline the disk on the target server), but when I call it from SQL Server, it just gets stuck and didn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you can use powershell remoting try `Start-Process` with the `-ComputerName` parameter instead of psexec. if not you can use wmi:
`$process = [WMICLASS]"\\$ComputerName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"; $process.Create("C:\Windows\system32\diskpart.exe /s C:\Test.txt")` If it still not works you can add credentials to both of the commands to avoid permission issues, google is your friend for this.

Comment: Might check my [answer on DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51885/507)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Diskpart` [requires](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770877.aspx) local administrator privileges. You don't assign those to the Sql Agent service. Instead, use an [proxy account](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx). Even better, [reconsider your process](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/system-configuration/stop-making-sql-server-dirty-work) and use something else than Sql Server for volume management.